# Basic question about wedge product

Tags: abstract-algebra

I read the definition of wedge product here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WedgeProduct.html,
but it is still not clear to me how to calculate it. What is the range of wedge product?
For example if I have two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^4$, namely $[1,0,0,0]^{T}$ and $[0,1,0,0]^{T}$, then what is their wedge product?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The wedge product of $e^1$ and $e^2$ is $e^1\wedge e^2$. Cannot be simplified furthermore.

Comment: Just to make things clear for the OP: the wedge product of two vectors is *not* a vector, but a "2-vector".

Comment: So how can I denote the range of wedge product? $\mathbb{R}^n$^$\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Usually it is denoted by $\Lambda^2(\mathbb R^n)$